# Every Friday afternoon, I crash and just sleep for 4 or 5 hours straight. Am i sick?

Tags: sleep

I'm not sure if this is the right Stack Exchange (but couldn't find a better one). It's been happening for quite a while, and I really wish I weren't like this, because it does take a lot of time away from me.

Mondays to Thursdays, I get 4-5 hours of sleep. On Fridays, I go to sleep around 4 or 5 pm in the afternoon, and wake up at 8 or 9 pm.  I eat some sort of dinner and try to be productive (but fail quite miserably on that part), and go back to sleep at like 12 or 1 am...

How can I stop doing this?

Comment: I don't think there is a Stack Exchange website for health. You should consult a professional health specialist, as online, anyone can *play* doctor and give you bad advice.

Comment: *How can I stop doing this?* Have you considered sleeping more than 4-5 hours a night?

Comment: Why do you only sleep 4-5 hours Monday to Thursday?

Comment: This is super off topic, but sounds to me like you either work too much to catch enough sleep or not enough so you don't get the chance to go to bed in the middle of a work day. But that's impossible to say for sure with what little information you offer